# Conversion problem with 'Feature to Raster': resulting Raster not visible in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-10.2, convert, spatial-analyst, esri-grid-format

I want to convert a Shapefile consisting of numerous point-features that each represent a specific height in my DEM to GRID-format so that i can then analyze it with Spatial Analyst.

Mysteriously, the conversion with "Feature to Raster" only takes 3 minutes (even tough the merging of the shape took 50) and the resulting GRID-layer is not visible in ArcMap or ArcCatalog.

There seen to be only two points in the resulting GRID, even though I picked height as value to assign information to the output raster.

What am I doing wrong here?

(When viewed completely, my Shape appears as a black area, but I assume that's because of the high density of point features. If I zoom in they are visible as separate points.

**Shapefile-PRJ:**

> PROJCS["DHDN_3_Degree_Gauss_Zone_3",GEOGCS["GCS_Deutsches_Hauptdreiecksnetz",DATUM["D_Deutsches_Hauptdreiecksnetz",SPHEROID["Bessel_1841",6377397.155,299.1528128]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Gauss_Kruger"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",3500000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",9.0],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",1.0],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]

The desired **resolution of my output-raster** is 1x1 m.

Comment: What is the projection information in the prj of the shapefile and what is the resolution of the Raster you are selecting at the output phase?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why "Feature to Raster" doesn't work, but found out that "Point to Raster" does!

I just used my Shape-Layer as in-feature, the height as value field, MEAN for cell_assignment (That's the one for DEMs, right!?) and my wanted cellsize.

Maybe this will help anyone in the future... :)